# Does SpringMVC supports loading of tile definitions without controller methods

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles2

I have some controllers which have nothing in them, i am just setting the viewname to model object and returning it . In the absence of these methods, does SpringMVC do the mapping directly through the tile definition? If yes, can you please tell how to do that.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` & `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController`:

- `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` gives the ability to route an URL directly to a controller,
- `UrlFilenameViewController` transform the received URL directy into a view name (e.g. `URL: /test.html` → `View name: test`).

Hereunder, the required Spring configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd">

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".tiles" />
            <property name="order" value="1" />
        </bean>

        <!-- For direct mapping between URL (i.e. index.html ←→ index) and the JSP 
            to render -->
        <bean id="urlFilenameViewController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
            <property name="order" value="1" />
            <property name="mappings">
                <util:map>
                    <entry key="/test.html" value-ref="urlFilenameViewController" />
                </util:map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

Be careful of the `<mcv:default-servlet-handler />` tag in your Spring configuration, it can make the above configuration failing (not returning null and default handler priority set to `Interger.MAX_VALUE` as explained in the Spring documentation).